# How to make UIPopoverPresentationController semi transparent for iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, popover

I used IB to create a segue to present another view a popover.

I added a code in `prepareForSegue` to deletage UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate to initial controller.

And I set presentation style:

```
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController,
     traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
      return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
}
```

This gives me a nice standard popover.

However, I want to make a semi-transparent popover.

I tried couple of things:

- I set background color in IB to "clear"
- I tried to set a alpha on the popover view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To have a view controller on top of another with transparency, you'll need to return `UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext`.

Comment: Oh... One more thing, you will need to setup background of Container View with some color that has alpha and the same is true to a view which is hosted inside of Container view.

Answer (score 1):

Concept: adjust the alpha value of the source view controller before segueing to the popover, and back to 1.0 again when it has been dismissed:

1. Set the source view controller as a popover delegate

   ```
   class MyVC: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
   ```
2. Set the delegate and source view alpha in the 'prepare for segue' function (on the way to the popover)

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       let controller = segue.destination as! ISACGlossaryTVC
       controller.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
       self.view.alpha = 0.2;
   }
   ```
3. Create delegate method popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover , and reset the source view alpha back when the pop-over has been dismissed

   ```
   func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
       self.view.alpha = 1.0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to achieve the desired affect with the posted answers.  However, these two lines did the trick for me:

```
popupVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.none
popupVC.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear // This needs to be set for the translucent appearance
```